# As a student, what license should I use on GitHub for my projects?

Tags: github

I'm a student currently studying Computer Science and I recently started uploading my personal projects to GitHub as public so that people who look at my resume at career fairs can see my work. I have the option to add a license template, and I don't know which one to choose. For now, I have it under `GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE`. Should I change it to another one, and if so which one?

For the record, I don't mind people using my code to look at it or run it, but I don't want people to claim it as their own. I didn't make anything ground-breaking but my work is still my work, for example I'm planning on uploading a mini-game which I created and I don't want someone else to take credit for it (even if it is shitty, it's still mine :P).

Thanks :D

Comment: You should reach a summary of some of the popular ones and decide which is right for you. https://choosealicense.com/licenses/

Comment: (Might be better suited for https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ , but regardless of that) : There are plenty of "How to decide which license to use"-Sites out there, and nobody can answer this question *for you* (here), because it depends on what **you** want.

Comment: BTW, the choice is probably not important, because it is unlikely that people would really use your code. I wish to you that it would happen, but attracting external users and contributors is not easy. I recommend reading [what is free software](http://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software) and using GPLv3+, but that is only my opinion, and you need to forge yours. It is basically a political choice (in the broadest sense of the expression), and you need to build your opinion by yourself.

Comment: You can use https://choosealicense.com/ which is hosted by Github as a "How to decide which license to use" site mentioned by Marco13.